# How to set cookies using spring

Tags: eclipse, spring, cookies

Can Anybody help me?

my class is

```
public class LoginTo implements Serializable

private HttpServletResponse response=null;

//Getters and Setters

PrintWriter pw = servletResponse.getWriter();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("url","Hello My Cookies Are Set Now");
cookie.setMaxAge(60*60); //1 hour
response.addCookie(cookie);
pw.println("Cookies created");
```

But it is giving me null pointer exception At response.addCookies(cookie);

Thanks

Comment: Please post the full code; and use Markdown formatting (see the 'help' link next to the edit box).

Comment: You didnt show any code that initializes the response variable. I guess that's why you have null pointer there

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
HttpServletResponse response=null;
```

here you are creating a object ,but you are initializing the object using new HttpServletResponse and you are trying to set the values.

Initialize the object before setting value.